# non-dynamic constructors in c++ with icpc?

Tags: c++, c++11, thread-local, default-constructor, icc

Is there a way to define a non-dynamic constructor which restricts the range of whichever default constructor lets me do

```
struct foo {
  int *bar;
};
static __thread foo myfoo[10] = {nullptr};
```

?

i.e., I want to do

```
class baz {
  public:
    baz() = default;
    constexpr baz(decltype(nullptr)) : qux(nullptr) { }

  private:
    int *qux;
};
static __thread baz mybaz[10] = {nullptr};
```

and have it work.

Currently, icpc tells me

```
main.cpp(9): error: thread-local variable cannot be dynamically initialized
  static __thread baz mybaz[10] = {nullptr};
                      ^
```

Comment: Is there any reason not to define constructor like this: `constexpr baz(int* ptr = nullptr) : qux(ptr) { }`

Comment: I want to allow implicit conversion from nullptr, but disallow implicit conversion from other pointers (see, e.g., `unique_ptr`).  If what you're suggesting is actually adding an additional constructor `baz() = default` or `constexpr baz() : qux(nullptr) { }`, then I could do that, but would `static __thread baz mybaz[10];` initialize the array to the default values?

Comment: Yes, it does, default constructor is used when array is not explicitly initialized in other way. Just add this default constexpr constructor and we'll see what happens...

Comment: g++ does not accept `constexpr baz() = default;`, it says "error: explicitly defaulted function ‘constexpr baz::baz()’ cannot be declared as constexpr because the implicit declaration is not constexpr"  However, icpc accepts it, and both seem to work fine if I get rid of the "= {nullptr}" and leave the constructor as-is.

Comment: However, the item 6 of §8.5 of the C++11 standard (http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2011/n3242.pdf) says "To default-initialize an object of type T means:
— if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
— if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
— otherwise, no initialization is performed.", which suggests that whether or not mybaz is zero-initialized is compiler-dependent.  Maybe?  I'm not very experienced in standard-reading

Comment: `if T is an array type, each element is default-initialized;` so not other choice for array. What does it means for your array element is defined by this part: `if T is a (possibly cv-qualiﬁed) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for T is called (and the
initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);` `Otherwise` means there - not a class type and not an  array, for example `int a;`

Comment: On the other hand, the standard also seems to say that static and thread-local globals are zero-initialized.

Comment: Your array is default initialized because its element type has constructors, it does not matter if it is local or global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
static __thread baz mybaz[10] = {nullptr};
```

is equivalent to:

```
static __thread baz mybaz[10] = {baz(nullptr), baz(), baz(), baz(), baz(), ..., baz()};
```

Because this is general rule that implicit initialization of an array element is by default constructor.

So either do this:

```
static __thread baz mybaz[10] = {nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, ..., nullptr};
```

Or make your default constructor also constexpr...